# Firebase Storage Rules for metadata update only

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

There doesn't seem to be a way to differentiate between an object create/overwrite versus a metadata update when writing Firebase Storage rules.

For my use case in particular, I would like users to be able to create an object if it does not exist, but once it exists, it may not be overwritten with a new object. However, the user should be able to update the object's metadata.

The Firebase Firestore rules allow you to differentiate between a create and an update using `create` and `update` instead of `write`, however I saw no such equivalent feature in the Storage rules documentation.

An example of Firestore rules:

```
allow create: if resource == null;
allow update: if true;
```

In Storage rules, it would be great if I could specify a rule like:

```
allow write: if resource == null || request.resource.metageneration != '1'
```

In the above hypothetical rule, we would allow a write if there is no currently existing object, or if the result of the requested write would not yield a metageneration of "1", since new objects have a metageneration of "1", but metadata updates yield a metageneration number greater than "1".

Of course, the above rule cannot work because the `request.resource` variable does not contain a `metageneration` property.

So, is there any other way to differentiate between an object overwrite versus a metadata update on an existing object?

Comment: please show what code you are using to update metadata of file in firebase storage

Comment: updateMetadata(adsRef, newMetadata).then((metadata) => {
        console.debug("AdCard: metadata", metadata)
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error("AdCard: metadata update error - ", error);
      });